# Error while comparing objects for equality in Java

Tags: java

I'm programing Ocean class,  Its a Homework, I need to make a Ocean where 'S' is a Shark and 'F' is a Fish.
The Ocean its a board so I use a matrix to make, if in the Ocean have one fish and one shark, the fish dead or if around shark there is no fishes the shark dead.

but when I try to compile show me:

```
error: not a statement


oceano2[i-1][j-1] == 'F';

                  ^
```

my variables...

```java
public class Ocean {
    private AquaticAnimal[][] oceano = new AquaticAnimal[][];
    private AquaticAnimal[][] oceano2 = new AquaticAnimal[][];
    static int defaultCapacity;
```

my constructor...

```java
public Ocean(int dimOceano) {
    if (dimOceano > this.defaultCapacity) {
        this.oceano = new AquaticAnimal[dimOceano][dimOceano];
        this.oceano2 = new AquaticAnimal[dimOceano][dimOceano];
    } else {
        this.oceano = new AquaticAnimal[defaultCapacity][defaultCapacity];
        this.oceano2 = new AquaticAnimal[defaultCapacity][defaultCapacity];
    }
}
```

Ocean's methods

```java
public int getCapacity(){
        return oceano.length; //regrese numero de filas
    }
.
.
.
```

I don't know how analyze the better way all places of my matrix, so I do one by one.
I have to analyze if around of fish or shark, if I have a fish and shark, the shark eats to fish, if there are no fishes the sharks dead, if only there are fishes born new fish.

```java
public void cycle() {
    int f = this.oceano.length;
    int c = this.oceano[0].length;

    for(int i = 1; i < f; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < c; j++) {
            while((j+1 < c) && (i+1 < f)) {

                if ((oceano2[i-1][j-1].equals('F'))&&(oceano2[i-1][j].equals(' '))&&(oceano2[i][j-1].equals(' '))&&(oceano2[i][j].equals(' '))) {
                    oceano2[i-1][j-1] = new AquaticAnimal('F');
                    } else if ((oceano2[i-1][j-1].equals(' '))&&(oceano2[i-1][j].equals('F'))&&(oceano2[i][j-1].equals(' '))&&(oceano2[i][j].equals(' '))){
.
.
.
```

this is me class `AquaticAnimal`, only a constructor and methods...

```java
public class AquaticAnimal{
    public static int maxStarveCycles = 0;
    private char animal;
    private int ciclosSinAlimentar;

    public AquaticAnimal(char animal){
        if(animal == 'F'){
            this.animal = animal;
            ciclosSinAlimentar = 0;
        } else {
            this.animal = animal;
            maxStarveCycles = 3;
        }
    }

    public char getTipo(){
        return animal;
    }

    public int getStarveCycles(){
        return ciclosSinAlimentar;
    }
.
.
.
```

I change

```java
==
```

to

```java
.equals()
```

and

```java
new AquaticAnimal('F);
```

but now I have the next error:

```java
error: cannot find symbol
       AquaticAnimal.maxStarveCycle = 3;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  You can't compare and assign between primitive characters and `AquaticAnimal` like that.  Does `AquaticAnimal` have a field of type `char` that you're trying to check/set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` use for comparison and `=` use for assignment. `oceano2[i-1][j-1] == 'F'` is a `boolean` expression. change this expression into statement and you cannont assign a character to Object. initialize proper object of `AquaticAnimal`  by `new` operator.

Change

```
oceano2[i-1][j-1] == 'F';
```

to (Parameterized Constructor)

```
oceano2[i-1][j-1] = new AquaticAnimal('F');// in case if its constructor has accept a chracter.
```

or (default constructor)

```
`oceano2[i-1][j-1] = new AquaticAnimal();`
```

And in you if statement you can compare by using `getTipo()` method

```
if(oceano2[i-1][j-1].getTipo() == 'F') { // your code }
```

Comment: that statement is used in "if()" condition. so, he may be expecting a boolean result.

Comment: why -1 ? can you explain ?

Comment: haha. I was talking about the piece in side the parentheses and you considered the piece in side braces. we both are right i think.

Comment: because my "for" start in 1, so I need the place [0][0] in the matrix.

Comment: thank you guys, now I have the next error:  error: cannot find symbol  AquaticAnimal.maxStarveCycle = 3;

Comment: @AbelArchila its a protected field. you can access it by its `get` method.

Comment: my method is  public void feed(){this.ciclosSinAlimentar = maxStarveCycles;} I try with oceano2.feed(), its correct access thus?

Comment: @AbelArchila make a setter for  `maxStarveCycles`  in this way. public void setMaxStarveCycles( int val) { this.maxStarveCycles = val; } and set your value by calling this method.
oceano2.setMaxStarveCycles(3);

Comment: @AbelArchila accept as an answer if it solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: the problem is that I have to use only my method, because I have a testOcean and use my methods.

Comment: can you share your complete code then i will suggest a solution

Comment: make maxStarveCycles  `static ` . `static public int maxStarveCycles` .

Comment: no man, I have to same error - Ocean.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
      AquaticAnimal.maxStarveCycle = 3; what do you think about?

Comment: Affyer making `public static int maxStarveCycles` issue will be resolved.

Comment: :( no man, the problem continues... Ocean.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
      AquaticAnimal.maxStarveCycle = 3;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable maxStarveCycle
  location: class AquaticAnimal

Comment: Your varibable name is `maxStarveCycles`  and you write `maxStarveCycle` . s is missing at end.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. `oceano2[i-1][j-1] == 'F'` is attempting to compare an `AquaticAnimal` to the character `F`. Add a call to get the type at the end: `oceano2[i-1][j-1].getTipo() == 'F'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
`oceano2` is Object of class `AquaticAnimal`.
```

So, to test equality you should use `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: Comparing an `AquaticAnimal` to a character is always going to be false, using `equals()` or `==`.

Comment: Then the entire approach to solve the problem is wrong?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Without knowing what the OP is trying to do, or at least what `AquaticAnimal` looks like, I don't think the question is answerable.